# Citet and citep not working with hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citep only works as cite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15394/citep-only-works-as-cite)

I used bibtex/natbib to compile my thesis, but unfortunately `\citet` and `\citep` don't connect with the hyperlink. In short:

1. `\cite{KEY}` gives me ==> {KEY}
2. `\citet{KEY}` gives me ==> Jones et al. {KEY} <===only KEY is hyperlinked
3. `\citep{KEY}` gives me ==> {KEY}
4. `\citeauthor{KEY}` gives me ==> Jones et al. <===hyperlinked but no date

I really don't want to use any of the above and tried doing something like

`\citeauthor{KEY}(\citeyear{KEY})`
    <==== curly brackets not
    hyperlinked.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? I want the citations to appear as:

Jones et al. (2004) or (Jones et al. 2004) fully hyperlinked.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx  You can format code fragments in your posts by using backticks (`). (I changed this for you.) What citation/bibliography  style are you using?

Comment: The behaviour you are describing isn't normal, so there must be something else that is interfering with this. Try doing the following: make a document that loads *only* `natbib` and `hyperref`, and see if that works as you expect.  (It should.) Then gradually add and remove other packages that your thesis uses until you can get the problem to arise, and add that minimal example to your question.

Comment: answered here 'http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15394/citep-only-works-as-cite'