# Citep only works as cite?

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

In an ideal situation using `natbib` and `abbrvnat`, citations e.g. `\citet{Jones2004}` and '\citep{Jones2004}' would have given **Jones et al. (2004)** and  **(Jones et al., 2004)** respectively.

Unfortunately I don't get that, instead I get

`\citep{Jones2004}` gives me ===> '(Jones, Giannini and Chang, 2004)'

Previously, @egreg, @lockstep: I followed your last idea by removing **numbers** from

`\usepackage[square,numbers,round,comma,sort&compress,longnamesfirst]{natbib}`,

and citations are picked quite well, except that '\citep{}' in the text doesn't work but if I try it on plain part of a page, it works. An example as below.

However, if I remove **longnamefirst**, it works but then I lose the style of having **longnamefirst** in the Bibliography content. Nevertheless, I've got another bibliographystyle that I tweaked but it would be useful if others could know this effect and may be the solution.

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}`
`\usepackage[round,authoryear,semicolon,sort&compress,longnamefirst]{natbib}`
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}`

`\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}`

`@misc{A01,`

`author = {Jones, A. and James, C., and Giannini, J.},`

`year = {2001},`

`title = {Title of journal article},`

`}`

`\end{filecontents}`

`\begin{document}`

Space is such an alien environment that attempting to work `\citep{A01}` in it requires new techniques and knowledge.\

`\citep{A01}\\`

`\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

`\bibliography{\jobname}`

`\end{document}`

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Haven't you asked this question already? [Citet and citep not working with hyperlink](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15378/2693). If your question has changed, it's better to edit the question, than ask a new one.

Comment: @lockstep: Your example worked fine, but still wondered why not in thesis.  
@egreg, @lockstep: I followed your last idea by removing **numbers** from `\usepackage[square,numbers,round,comma,sort&compress,longnamesfirst]{natbib}`, and everything worked fine! Great idea!!!

Comment: Its surprising why I still get this problem....'\citep' still gives citation as '\citep', despite removing 'Numbers' from the '\usepackage[...,numbers,...]{natbib}'. In fact, it fluctuates...some times it works well, sometimes it doesn't. I tried compiling more than 2 times but to no avail. Any idea? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This minimal example works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{A01}

\citep{A01}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: I get the OP's behavior if I load natbib with the `numbers` option, with which `\citep` behaves exactly as `\cite` as per natbib's documentation (bottom of page 4).

Comment: @egreg: Good catch -- maybe the OP didn't mention the `numbers` option, or the documentclass he uses activates it. You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @BrettHarry: The answer to your question is: "Remove the `numbers` option."

Comment: @lockstep @ egreg : Problem again. I realised that removing 'Numbers' from 'Usepackage' worked but only for some paragraphs. When I '\citep{21}' at a plain page, it works, but not in paragraphs. Any idea why this mix up occur? I recompiled more than twice but to no avail.

Comment: @BrettHarry: Please update your original question and include a minimal working example (i.e. one that compiles and shows the problem).

Comment: @lockstep This page seems a bit cluttered with questions/answers/questions. Is it possible I edit it to make the question visible? Or I tweak the question in some way to a new page? Cheers

Comment: @BrettHarry: First, try to find out the difference between my working example and your non-working document. Then edit your question to include a compilable (!) example -- use the `filecontents` environment like I did.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks for the pointer! I'm still novice when it comes to creating synthetic example:-( I have edited it @ top of page

Answer (score 8):

When natbib is loaded with the `numbers` option, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[...,numbers,...]{natbib}
```

the command `\citep` behaves like the usual `\cite`, while `\citet` prints "Author name(s) [x]", where "x" is the numeric reference. In this case only the number is made a link to the bibliography. On the contrary, with the default author-year citation system, all the "Author name(s) (year)" given by `\citet` and "(Author name(s), year)" given by `\citep` become a link to the bibliography.